# Is there any utility function to convert a CString to URL-Encoded UTF-8 string?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, unicode, mfc

I have the following:

```
CString gText = _T("Π Σ Ω");
```

And I want to obtain:

```
%CE %A0 %CE %A3 %CE %A9
```

Any conversion routines like `WideStringToMultiByte` or `CT2A` give me the binary back. In reality, I want the hex escaped. Is there any conversion utility in MFC for this? Any third party lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you might use the

```
sprintf(hexcode_string, "U+%02x", MultibyteStringFromWideStringToMultiByte[j]);
```

for each character and then combine the strings.

Comment: See edit. I just found out that I can use URL Encoded UTF-8 hex.